# How can I get git to automatically match a remote branch by name?

Tags: git

I'm often working with cloned repos, having an "origin" (my) and "upstream" (original source). I'm always cloning the "origin" repo from github for working on it and create PRs and from time to time need to pull from "upstream" to sync with the latest changes going on there.

After `git clone <origin uri>` I can do

```
git push/pull
```

without specifying the branch since its already tracked; however doing this on the other remote

```
git pull upstream
```

when e.g. on `master` branch I would like git to actually do

```
git pull upstream master
```

instead of:

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

I understand I can configure the tracking remote but I'd like to know if this can be automatic as long as branch names are identical.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below config, so whenever you checkout a new branch from remote, it will be automatically tracked, without needing you to setup tracking with `--set-upstream-to` or `--track`

```
git config --global branch.autosetupmerge true
```

Comment: Unfortunately not: error: invalid key: branch.autosetupmerge=true

Comment: Still no: same original message on `git pull upstream`

Comment: @andig it will only setup tracking when you newly checkout a remote branch which does not already exist in your local copy. If all your changes are pushed to remote, you can delete your local branch and check out the branch again, and then try. Any new branch you freshly checkout in the future will have tracking setup for you.

Comment: Updated question- then it's not what I'm looking for since I always clone from origin but what the "matching" behaviour when pulling from "upstream", too?

Answer (score 0):

> You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify a
>   branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your
>   current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

Looking at the message, the first thing is as you haven't configured `upstream` as your default remote. So, first, you need to set it as the default remote like:
`git config branch.branch_name.remote upstream`
Now, you need to specify a branch from where you want to fetch the commits. You can specify that by running 
`git config branch.branch_name.merge refs/heads/branch_name`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `--track` or `--set-upstream-to(-u)`:

```
$ git branch --track master upstream/master
```

For the current branch:

```
$ git branch -u upstream/master
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=upstream/master
```

This'll assign the remote-tracking branch `upstream/master` to your `master` branch so that it's automatically fetched from in the next `git pull` invocation.

From the man page:

```
   -t, --track
       When creating a new branch, set up branch.<name>.remote and branch.<name>.merge
       configuration entries to mark the start-point branch as "upstream" from the new
       branch. This configuration will tell git to show the relationship between the 
       two branches in git status and git branch -v. Furthermore, it directs git pull
       without arguments to pull from the upstream when the new branch is checked out.

   -u <upstream>, --set-upstream-to=<upstream>
       Set up <branchname>'s tracking information so <upstream> is considered 
       <branchname>'s upstream branch. If no <branchname> is specified, then it defaults
       to the current branch.
```